# Can claim based security be used to provide user access to data?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I am not sure if this question is appropriate here, so please be gentle.

I recently read about `.NET Claim based security` as I understand it, it is used to control a user's access to different functionality.

In a bottle: a user can claim access to a certain web-page, update or delete commands.

By chance I am working on a project which involves houses and people that manage them (certain people get access to certain houses).

The question is rather simple: is it appropriate to give a person the neccesarry read/write right for a certain house through the ClaimsAuthorization Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can add your own claims to handle this, there is a nice article on the subject here: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/going-beyond-usernames-and-roles.aspx

What you have to worry about is how big the cookies become by caring around extra claims.

Comment: Do you think, if the cookie tends to get quite large, it's better to check the claims server side stored in cache?

Comment: It's been my experience that yes, it's better to store that In Memory.  (Cache may not work depending on your ability to recreate the data)